# Creating Array formula that does text-based matching based on criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to improve from a standard formula, to create an array formula, that returns the number of text matches between 2 data sets based on set criteria.

Please refer to this Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PqBn6PPF0L21pK9fwA8jVAWp3D2_diftg4MCIz0oBGg/edit#gid=1979770676

My overarching aim is to matchmake between a set of mentors and mentees, using a text-matching scoring system.

**Baseline MVP**

I've first did this using match-based scoring, with each text match between a mentor and mentee giving 1 point, and the sum of the number of matches between each mentor and mentee will give the final score for that mentor-mentee pair. This is represented in a matrix in the "Matching MVP" tab, with the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(IF(B$1=Sandbox!$A$2:$A$20,Sandbox!$D$2:$D$20,"x"),IF($A2=Sandbox!$A$23:$A$35,Sandbox!$D$23:$D$35,"o")))
```

**What I have done:**

To further refine the scoring, I want to add an element of "intensity", where if a mentor/mentee has more than 1 tag in the same category, the match-score in that category between a mentor/mentee pair will be scaled downwards by a factor of 1/sqrt(no. of tags in that category).

For example, if mentee 1 has the "South Korea" and "Japan" tags in the "Country" Category, their "Country" Category score will be scaled down as the following: **Match Score * 1/sqrt(2)**, to give an intensity-adjusted score for that category.

This intensity factor is applied for each category, and the final match-score will be a sum-product of the arrays of the intensity factors of each category (see G11:G13), and the raw match-counts in each category for a mentor-mentee pair (see K11:K13). The final result can be seen in cell G17.

The intensity-factor computation is an array formula in G11 with the following:

```
=ArrayFormula(1/sqrt(COUNTIF(IF(G3=$A$2:$A$20,$B$2:$B$20,""),G4:G6)))
```

and the raw match-scores is a standard drag-down formula from K11:K13, referencing cells G4:G6 for the categories:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(FILTER(IF($G$3=$A$2:$A$20,$D$2:$D$20,""),REGEXMATCH(IF($G$3=$A$2:$A$20,$D$2:$D$20,""),G4)),FILTER(IF($G$2=$A$23:$A$35,$D$23:$D$35,""),REGEXMATCH(IF($G$2=$A$23:$A$35,$D$23:$D$35,""),G4))))
```

**Where I need help:**

I want to replace the formulas in K11:K13 with an **array formula** instead, that returns the exact same result. This is because I want to nest all the array formulas into one sum-product, which can then fit very nicely into my matrix in the "Matching MVP" tab, replacing the simple match-scoring MVP. The number of categories in G4:G6 will also **expand**, and I want the array formula to account for that.

It is entirely possible that the final result I want (in G17) can be accomplished in an entirely different way, so do feel free to try other methods of applying the intensity factors to the match-scoring.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!